# Error handling the SmtpClient object

Tags: .net, gmail, smtpclient

I'm using the code below to process the results of mail sending using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient and am having problems trapping a true 'send failure' vs 'opps...let me try that again, oh great, it worked' conditions.

My SendMail method closes with this:

```
    smtp.SendCompleted += SendCompletedCallback;
    smtp.SendAsync(Msg, userState);
```

and the callback:

```
    private static void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var msg= (MailMessage)e.UserState;
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            Logger("Cancelled - " + msg.Subject.ToString()+ " : " + msg.To.ToString());
        }
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Logger("ERROR: " + msg.To.ToString() + " : " + e.Error.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Logger("EmailGateway: " + msg.Subject.ToString());
        }

    }
```

The problem I'm finding is multiple passes of the same message thru the `if (e.Error != null)` branch - sometimes the subsequent attempt completes successfully, sometimes not.

In other words, in my Log, sometimes I'm seeing 2 lines on the same message (a true error condition because the message was **not** delivered) but I'm also seeing instances where the Log shows just a single error but then further it logs a success. So sometimes, even though the Log shows a error for a given message - the mail was in fact, sent.

It's probably worth pointing out that my Log is not showing any messages as 'Canceled'. It's not like ***'we'll give it 2 tries then we hit 'cancelled'***. In instances showing 2 attempts with nothing sent (a true fail condition) it looks as though the remote smtp server triggered the error condition twice on the same message.

So if I want to add more robust error handling beyond just logging stuff, how can I tell true error conditions vs. a retry that results in success?

Here's the full exception being returned. I should parse for 'Try again later' before logging the error condition, shouldn't I?

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Service not available, closing
>   transmission channel. The server response was: 4.7.0 Temporary System
>   Problem.  Try again later (WS). e22sm1141297yba.20     at
>   System.Net.Mail.SendMailAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)     at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.EndSendMail(IAsyncResult result)     at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendMailCallback(IAsyncResult result)

thx

Comment: I would add a counter
Increment it 
    using System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref i);
and add the time to logging to see if you really get errors for sent messages

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion but issues of threading are outside my current learned curve. You're suggesting that the remote isn't actually sending (in the 'errors for sent messages' instance) - that the framework is interpreting lack of response as an error condition?

Comment: The callback function can be called out of sync which will make life harder to see the order of events. I would suggest adding more details to userState like a counter or datetime....

Comment: I appreciate you're re-stating your original suggestion but I'm unclear as to the foundation. Is adding a timestamp going to preclude the callback being called out of synch? It looks to me like my current code is giving me false errors which makes it impossible to correctly handle the error. If adding a timestamp just gives me another value to check - i don't see how/where that check is expected to be carried out.